# EF5 Migration Update-Database -Script Error

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations

I've been using Visual Studio 2012 RC with trial license with no problems.  I purchased Visual Studio 2012 Professional yesterday, installed the latest version, and installed Update 1.

I have a solution/project I've been working on for many years.  It has many migrations in it.  I ran my first `add-migration TableX_NewField` and `update-database -sourcemigration:TableX_PreviousNewField` in this latest version.

They both ran with no problems.

Then I ran `update-database -script -sourcemigration:TableX_PreviousNewField` and received the following:

```
PM> update-database -script -sourcemigration:TableX_PreviousNewField
Applying code-based migrations: [201301151003149_TableX_NewField].
Applying code-based migration: 201301151003149_TableX_NewField.
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8004000C): User canceled out of save dialog (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8004000C (OLE_E_PROMPTSAVECANCELLED))
  at EnvDTE.ItemOperations.OpenFile(String FileName, String ViewKind)
  at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Utilities.DomainDispatcher.OpenFile(String fileName)
  at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Utilities.DomainDispatcher.OpenFile(String fileName)
  at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Extensions.ProjectExtensions.NewSqlFile(Project project, String contents)
  at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.UpdateDatabaseCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
  at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
User canceled out of save dialog (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8004000C (OLE_E_PROMPTSAVECANCELLED))
```

I've ran windows updates.  Checked updates with NuGet.  Restarted my computer.  Still have error.

Comment: Do you have any additional Visual Studio extensions installed besides NuGet?

Comment: Also, have you tried repairing Visual Studio?

Comment: @Brice Yes, the extensions listed are "Microsoft Developer Tools", "Visual Studio Extensions for Windows Library for JavaScript", and "Web Essentials 2012".

Comment: @Brice I successfully repaired Visual Studio 2012. Tried the 'update-database -script' again and had the same error returned.

Comment: You could try installing the [SQL Server Data Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/jj650015). This should allow it to open in a SQL editor instead of using ItemOperations.OpenFile().

Comment: I have installed the latest SQL Server Data Tools (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh297027) and that seems to have resolved the issue.

Comment: I highly disagree with the closing decision. This question is VERY likely to help a lot of future visitors.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

I noticed in visual studio, going to SQL menu, Transact-SQL Editor, New Query... gave a dialog about the tools not working with the server installed. Installing SQL Server Data Tools - December 2012 update ([Sql Server Data Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/jj650015)) fixed the problem

Comment: was skeptical but worked for me - was using command `Update-Database -Script -SourceMigration:0` which gets full SQL from scratch

Comment: you do need to restart Visual studio after installing the tools

Comment: Using Web Platform Installer do a search for Data Tools and install the Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio 2012, Released 12/10/2012.

Comment: I just experienced the same error with Visual Studio 2012 Update 2 and EF 4.3. This had been working fine but two possible changes on my machine that may have broken it were an update to Nuget package manager 2.6.40627.9000 and a failed VS2012.3 update that was rolled back. Applying **SQL Server Data Tools - June 2013 update** fixed it for me.

Comment: As Simon_Weaver said, you have to restart Visual Studio. If you don't restart VS, the SQL > Transact SQL > New Query menu will STOP showing the original error, but the Package Manager Console will continue throwing errors. Restart the whole thing!

Answer (score 4):

This issue is resolved.  I uninstalled and then installed and the problem was not resolved.  I then did two things at the same time; so I do not know which resolved the issue:

1. Deleted all folders and files in %temp%.
2. Ran devenv /resetsettings.

Hope this helps anyone who runs into a similar issue.

Comment: Did same thing, said skip to deleting files that required admin or was in use. And it worked.